# Unable to open ASP.NET Core website's Module in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, iis-10

I've deployed `ASP.NET Core 1.1.1` app in `IIS-10` on `Windows 10` following [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/publish-and-deploy-asp-net-core-mvc-on-iis/) tutorial. But when I try to open `Modules` in `IIS`, I get the following error [For clear view you can click on the image to zoom in]:

[image]

**Note**:

1. It's a development machine and already has installed as shown below:
   [image]
2. The app pool for the app is as follows:

[image]

**And the Web.config file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**UPDATE**: Issue may have been related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45722081/1232087) post

Comment: Could you change it to `<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\YOUR_WEB_APP_NAMESPACE.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `ASP.NET Core Module` is installed separately from the SDK and I needed to install `ASP.NET Core Module` for the above issue to be resolved as explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45750010/1232087). Thanks to `@natemcmaster` for helping me resolve the issue.