# ASPNETCoreModule not installed with .NET Core SDK

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, iis-10

I installed `VS 2017` along with `.NET Core SDK` on Windows 10. But it did not install `ASPNETCoreModule` as shown in figure 2 below. I thought `.NET Core SDK` should have installed it implicitly - and one does not have to install it separately. **NOTE**: I'm trying to publish my asp.net core app to IIS and the publish process requires `ASPNETCoreModule` as explained in the above link and also in this official [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis).

[image]

**ASPNETCoreModule is missing**:

[image]

Comment: ANCM is not part of the .NET Core SDK, I'm not sure what your intent with this question here is

Comment: @MartinUllrich Good question. I've added a **NOTE** to my post above to answer it to other readers as well.

Comment: "I thought ...“ That's not a valid challenge against Microsoft's design. The article you linked to in fact says clearly how to install, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle

Comment: The docs say install "select the Hosting Bundle Installer link to download the .NET Core Hosting Bundle." This has caught me out too :(

Answer (score 32, accepted):

ASP.NET Core Module is installed separately from the SDK. You can download the current version 2.0.0 here. https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.0-download.md#windows-server-hosting

See https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md for a list of other releases.

Comment: Thanks for this one, it helped me after struggling for several hours!!

Comment: @natemcmaster Thank you for coming to the rescue. I had read somewhere online that havaving either `.NET Core SDK` or the `Win Server hosting` in installed programs should signal `ASPNETCoreModule` is there. It now turns out that info was incorrect. I installed  `ASPNETCoreModule` separately and I can host our `ASP.NET Core` apps on `IIS`.

Comment: The link provided was not the one I needed. This one was: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: This helps me after struggling for 2 days!

Comment: I installed dot net core host bundle but its not appearing in iis modules..anyone pls help me.

Answer (score 4):

> ASP.NET Core Module is installed separately from the SDK

It's not true since the release of 2.1. I'm experiencing the same issue on Windows Server 2016. The module was installed on developer PC after uninstalling old versions / installing 2.1 a few times, but still struggling with the same issue in 2016. **%SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\aspnetcore.dll** is still missing.

Comment: According to this one https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/4181#issuecomment-394494701  it is still true, this module should be installed as separate bundle, its not included to SDK

Answer (score 1):

In order to run .net core apps on IIS you need to have installed the ASP.NET Core Module ( [the way it works is explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1) ) that comes:
1 - with the SDK 2.1,
2 - With the Hosting Bundle Installer that bundles the .Net Core and the ASP.NET Core Runtime into a single bundler.

you can have both from the [download page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows)

If you are a developer computer you already have the Module with the SDK, I think is better to have on Sever computer only the hosting bundle

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check your IIS configurations, in case Shared configuration is configured in your IIS then normal installation of dotnet hosting bundle package wont work,
to make it work you need to install bundle package by command line with the argument as below:

```
dotnet-hosting-{VERSION}.exe OPT_NO_SHARED_CONFIG_CHECK=1
```

you can refer [ASP.NET Core Module with an IIS Shared Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

This solution work for me because we are using the shared configuration in IIS